# iOS FBLoginView required permissions

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm creating an FBLoginView and setting the permissions:

```
self.facebookLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
```

But when the prompt is shown to the user they can disable the email option. Is there a way to specify that this is required. My whole purpose of asking for FB login is to get the email address for authentication.

Comment: call the deniy permission when u need

Comment: Try using "basic_info" permission

Comment: basic_info isn't valid. Tells me to use public_profile, user_friends instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what deny permission means. How do I do this?